# brackets stopped responding when using bootstrap min css file

Tags: css, adobe-brackets

> I am using brackets as text editor. Bootstrap.min css file is stopped
>      responding on brackets. Html file is working fine, but when switch on to css 
>      file brackets hangs. Brackets worked fine on restart. When css file loads the 
>      problem started again. The file works fine on other text editors, but not on 
>      brackets. Apart from bootstrap css other css files works on brackets. I 
>      disabled the extensions in brackets and tried again. it's still not 
>      working.

Answer (score 0):

What specific copy of Bootstrap are you using? I tried downloading Bootstrap 3.3.4 from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download), but that `bootstrap.min.css` file opens just fine in Brackets.

Your best bet is to [file a bug](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues) and be sure to include:

- A link to the *exact* CSS file that's causing the problem
- If you have to put your cursor in a specific part of the file, or move your mouse over a specific piece of code, before the problem happens - identify the exact location
- Mention in the bug that you already tried disabling extensions (*Debug > Reload Without Extensions*), otherwise someone will probably ask you to try that first :-)

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.3.2. problem is not with opening bootstrap.min.css file on brackets, but it's stops working after few seconds then bracket hangs. most of the time have to use task manager end task or end process to close brackets when it's hangs. sometimes  i'm able to close brackets normally. also tried with bootstrap 3.3.4, but problem still persists. had gone to the file bug url that you mentioned. i don't know how to file a bug.

Comment: You can use this URL to file a bug: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/new (or press the green "New Issue" button at the original URL). **But first** try this: put bootstrap.min.css in an _empty_ folder, then open the folder as your Brackets project (_File > Open Folder_). If you open the file after that, does the problem still happen? If not, try adding other files from your original project into this folder until you find the one that causes Brackets to hang.

Comment: Tried bootstrap min css in an empty folder. it's behaved comparatively better, but there is that same problem occurs. Its works fine then hangs for a few seconds then again its works. this cycle continues.  Filed a bug as you mentioned and hopefully this might help